# Is it possible to unlink a linked record using the Relay Modern imperative mutation API?

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I would like write a mutation `updater` that unlinks a linked record from another record.

For example, suppose I have the following in my store:

```
client:root {
  user: {__ref: "someid"}
}
```

I am looking for a way to unlink `user` and `client:root`. `user` is a nullable field. I would like subscribers that are interested in the `user` field to see it has gone `null`.

Right now the only way I am seeing to unlink this field is to delete the node from the store. I've tried setting the link to null using `setLinkedRecord` but that throws an error.

Comment: Have you tried `setValue` ? https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/mutations.html#setvalue-value-mixed-name-string-args-variables-recordproxy

Comment: Yeah setting `null` results in an error.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: That the value can't be `null`

Comment: Need the exact error message to investigate

Comment: Line here https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/6d87a701de69ce1e271895ff689ddbda2b39b4c2/packages/relay-runtime/mutations/RelayRecordProxy.js#L150 says `null` should pass

Comment: Oh that’s for leaf values. `user` here is not scalar. I thought that was clear given the `__ref` in the example

Answer (score 1):

`.setLinkedRecored()` expects the first argument to be an instance of `RecordProxy`. Use `.setValue()` for unlinking nodes, as [whitep4nther commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859833/is-it-possible-to-unlink-a-linked-record-using-the-relay-modern-imperative-mutat#comment80835134_46859833).

```
store.getRoot().setValue(undefined, 'user');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for adding this answer. I must have misread @whitep4nther's comments when he left them because what you're saying makes sense. I'll try this out and upvote/accept next time I get a chance.

Comment: This doesn't work. Setting a linked field with to `undefined` with `setValue()` doesn't alter the store.

Comment: It's strange. In my use case, setting `null` or `undefined` in `commitLocalUpdate` callback works without any issue.

Comment: Yeah setting it `null` works. But then the record is linked, just null

Comment: I added an example app for simple demonstration of unlinking records. https://github.com/smagch/relay-example-unlinking-records
You can see working example: https://smagch.github.io/relay-example-unlinking-records/

Answer (score 0):

I was just fighting with this as well, and after digging through the relay codebase, I decided there isn't an appropriate way to go about this right now. I've [opened an issue here](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2210).